# pyparsing for querying a database of chemical elements

Tags: pyparsing

I would like to parse a query for a database of chemical elements.

The database is stored in a xml file. Parsing that file produces a nested dictionary that is stored in a singleton object that inherit from collections.OrderedDict.

Asking for an element will give me an ordered dictionary of its corresponding properties
(i.e. ELEMENTS['C'] --> {'name':'carbon','neutron' : 0,'proton':6, ...}).

Conversely, asking for a propery will give me an ordered dictionary of its values for all the elements (i.e. ELEMENTS['proton'] --> {'H' : 1, 'He' : 2} ...).

A typical query could be:

```
mass > 10 or (nucleon < 20 and atomic_radius < 5)
```

where each 'subquery' (i.e. mass > 10) will return the set of elements that matches it.

Then, the query will be converted and transformed internally to a string that will be evaluated further to produce a set of the indexes of the elements that matched it. In that context the operators and/or are not boolean operator but rather ensemble operator that acts upon python sets.

I recently sent a post for building such a query. Thanks to the useful answers I got, I think that I did more or less the job (I hope on a nice way !) but I still have some questions related to pyparsing.

Here is my code:

```
import numpy

from pyparsing import *

# This import a singleton object storing the datase dictionary as
# described earlier
from ElementsDatabase import ELEMENTS

and_operator = oneOf(['and','&'], caseless=True) 
or_operator  = oneOf(['or' ,'|'], caseless=True) 

# ELEMENTS.properties is a property getter that returns the list of 
# registered properties in the database
props = oneOf(ELEMENTS.properties, caseless=True)

# A property keyword can be quoted or not.
props = Suppress('"') + props + Suppress('"') | props
# When parsed, it must be replaced by the following expression that 
# will be eval later.
props.setParseAction(lambda t : "numpy.array(ELEMENTS['%s'].values())" % t[0].lower())

quote = QuotedString('"')
integer = Regex(r'[+-]?\d+').setParseAction(lambda t:int(t[0]))
float_  = Regex(r'[+-]?(\d+(\.\d*)?)?([eE][+-]?\d+)?').setParseAction(lambda t:float(t[0]))

comparison_operator = oneOf(['==','!=','>','>=','<', '<='])
comparison_expr = props + comparison_operator + (quote | float_ | integer)
comparison_expr.setParseAction(lambda t : "set(numpy.where(%s)%s%s)" % tuple(t))

grammar = Combine(operatorPrecedence(comparison_expr, [(and_operator, 2, opAssoc.LEFT) (or_operator, 2, opAssoc.LEFT)]))

# A test query
res = grammar.parseString('"mass     "  >  30 or (nucleon == 1)',parseAll=True)

print eval(' '.join(res._asStringList()))
```

My question are the following:

```
1 using 'transformString' instead of 'parseString' never triggers any 
  exception even when the string to be parsed does not match the grammar. 
  However, it is exactly the functionnality I need. Is there is a way to do so ?

2 I would like to reintroduce white spaces between my tokens in order 
that my eval does not fail. The only way I found to do so it the one 
implemented above. Would you see a better way using pyparsing ?
```

sorry for the long post but I wanted to introduce in deeper details its context. BTW, if you find this approach bad, do not hesitate to tell it me!

thank you very much for your help.

Eric

Answer (score 1):

do not worry about my concern, I found a work around. I used the SimpleBool.py example shipped with pyparsing (thanks for the hint Paul).

Basically, I used the following approach:

```
1 for each subquery (i.e. mass > 10), using the setParseAction method, 
I joined a function that returns the set of eleements that matched 
the subquery

2 then, I joined the following functions for each logical operator (and, 
or and not):

def not_operator(token):

    _, s = token[0]

    # ELEMENTS is the singleton described in my original post
    return set(ELEMENTS.keys()).difference(s)

def and_operator(token):

    s1, _, s2 = token[0]

    return (s1 and s2)

def or_operator(token):

    s1, _, s2 = token[0]

    return (s1 or s2)

# Thanks for Paul for the hint.
grammar = operatorPrecedence(comparison_expr,
          [(not_token, 1,opAssoc.RIGHT,not_operator),
          (and_token, 2, opAssoc.LEFT,and_operator),
          (or_token, 2, opAssoc.LEFT,or_operator)])

Please not that these operators acts upon python sets rather than 
on booleans.
```

And that does the job.

I hope that this approach will help anyone of you.

Eric

Comment: Well done! Glad you were able to puzzle this through. This is also very similar to the search engine query parser in "Getting Started With Pyparsing"

Comment: Oh, by the way - if you try "cond_a and cond_b and cond_c", then you will get `[[cond_a, 'and', cond_b, 'and', cond_c]]` passed to your parse action. Easiest way to handle this is with slicing: change and_operator to `return all(token[0][::2])` and or_operator to `return any(token[0][::2])`.